# JQuery appendTo appending at top not at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, append

How can I append the selected class to the bottom by using `appendTo` function?

Ajax Code which returns html string:

```
function GetRow() {
        var form = $('form');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Journals/CreateJournalDetails',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#partial').append('<tr>' + data + '</tr>');
                $('.CheckDetails').appendTo('#partial1');
                form.data('validator', null);
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            }
        });
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            --header here
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="partial"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            --header here
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="partial1"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

`CreateJournalDetails` partial code:

```
    @model SimplyAccounting.Models.TransactionViewModels.JournalDetailsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("JournalDetailsViewModel"))
{
    <tr class="CheckDetails" id="@Model.Guid">
        <td>@Model.Guid</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Check_Number, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Check_Number, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
        --code etc here..
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="DocumentDetails" id="@Model.Guid">
        <td>@Model.Guid</td>
        <td scope="row">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gla_Code, Model.Gla_List, "--please select an item--", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm glaSelect" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gla_Code, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
        --code etc here..

        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="delete" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="javascript: deleteBook(document.getElementById('@Model.Guid'))"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
    </tr>

}
```

I have generated the a Guid to validate if the row is correct, sample output:
[image]

And when I trigger the `GetRow` function, sample output
[image]

the first table #partial, the row is added at the bottom but the second table #partial1 row is added at the top.

How can I possibly fix this issue so that both rows will be added at the bottom?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, `appendTo` is doing what expected. The reverse ordering is due to the wrong CSS selector. What happen in your code is that.

1. From the ajax response(`$('#partial').append('<tr>' + data + '</tr>');`), table row `CheckDetails` and `DocumentDetails` are appended to table body `partial`. table body `partial1` is empty.

```
    <tbody id="partial">
      <tr class="CheckDetails">1st...</tr>
      <tr class="DocumentDetails">1st...</tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="partial1"></tbody>
```

2. Then **ALL** items with class `CheckDetails` (`$('.CheckDetails').appendTo('#partial1');`) are appended to table body `partial1`.Everything is fine at these step.

```
    <tbody id="partial">
      <tr class="DocumentDetails">1st...</tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="partial1">
      <tr class="CheckDetails">1st...</tr>
    </tbody>
```

3. However when we repeat step 1 and 2 for next item.

```
    <tbody id="partial">
      <tr class="DocumentDetails">1st...</tr>
      <tr class="CheckDetails">2nd...</tr>
      <tr class="DocumentDetails">2nd...</tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="partial1">
      <tr class="CheckDetails">1st...</tr>
    </tbody>
```

Since all **ALL** items with class `CheckDetails` are appended to table body `partial1`, all table row with class `CheckDetails` (1st and 2nd) will be removed to parent and append to table body `partial1`. **As 2nd row is above 1st row in the html**, the result is

```
    <tbody id="partial">
      <tr class="DocumentDetails">1st...</tr>
      <tr class="DocumentDetails">2nd...</tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="partial1">
      <tr class="CheckDetails">2nd...</tr>
      <tr class="CheckDetails">1st...</tr>
    </tbody>
```

To fix the problem, keep your code to do what it is supposed to, nothing more nothing less. Update `$('.CheckDetails').appendTo('#partial1');` to `$('tbody#partial>tr.CheckDetails').appendTo('#partial1');` so that only table row belongs to `partial` is append to `partial1`.